# Converting String to time like secondminute in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to convert string to time in smarty like secondminute() function in php.

My code in php is like that :

```
var_dump(($result->getAvgtimeonpage()));
```

It's returning (int78)

When I add

```
var_dump(secondMinute($result->getAvgtimeonpage()));
```

It's returning : string(5) "01:18"

Now question , can somebody tell me how to return string convert by secondminute in smarty ? 
I tried smarty_date_fomat and it's not working properly.

Thank you for your advices, best regards.

Comment: Which smarty version using??

Answer (score 1):

There is not such secondminute function in php so I suppose that it's a function created by you. If you're working with small values, you can use php's gmdate:

```
{"i:s"|@gmdate:78}
```

or, for values of more than 1 hour and up to 24 hours:

```
{"H:i:s"|@gmdate:78}
```

Or also create your own smarty secondminute plugin modifier http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.writing.tpl.